# Create temp file for a sandboxed Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, app-store, sandbox, temporary-files

My app is *sandboxed* (as per the latest App Store guidelines), and I want to create some temporary files.

Am I allowed to do so? If "yes", WHERE am I allowed to do it? Is there any prespecified path? (And a command to access that path?)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer rather than adding it to the question body.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use the `NSTemporaryDirectory()` function, which will find and return the appropriate temporary folder for your application (regardless of sandbox status, OS version, and a host of other things). Take a look at [this Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/temporary-files-and-folders-in-cocoa.html) post for much more detail about `NSTemporaryDirectory()` and other temporary directory-related details.

Answer (score 5):

There is a good article about temporary directories on NSHipster:

http://nshipster.com/nstemporarydirectory/

The author suggests this code which is working perfectly with sandboxed apps as well:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *globallyUniqueString = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
NSString *tempDirectoryPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:globallyUniqueString];
NSURL *tempDirectoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempDirectoryPath isDirectory:YES];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:tempDirectoryURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```