# sandboxing an existing OSX app

Tags: macos, app-store, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I have an existing OSX app that supports OSX 10.5 onwards. I want to publish it to the AppStore and therefore I need to sandbox the app. I guess sandbox app should be supporing 10.7 onwards.

- The app uses a folder in the username directory to create temp files etc
- It also copies a sql db file which already has empty tables to the same temp folder and upates records as the app is used.
- Furthermore if there is a crash it picks up logs from the crashlog folder of osx and requests user to submit them to developer.

Question

with a sanbox app, where do I store temp files ?
Where should I place the db file which can be read/witten to + new App update should be able to find exsting db file.
Should the custom code for crash reporter be kept or be made redundant ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where do I store temp files ?

[In the directory recommended by `NSTemporaryDirectory()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12375149/149341) (This applies to both sandboxed and non-sandboxed applications.)

> Where should I place the db file which can be read/witten to

In your application's Application Support directory. [Use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` to find it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8430843/149341), then append your application's name. Again, this is the same whether you're sandboxed or not.

> new App update should be able to find exsting db file.

Not possible. You can ask the user to locate the existing file with a `NSOpenPanel`, but you can't open it yourself, because it'd be outside your sandbox.

> Should the custom code for crash reporter be kept or be made redundant ?

You'll need to remove it, because it won't work under sandboxing — crash reports are not stored to your sandbox. You will receive crash reports for your application through iTunes Connect.

Alternatively, you may want to look into a third-party crash reporting service like [PLCrashReporter](https://www.plcrashreporter.org/).

Comment: Just need clarification. When new app update is published if it can not find existing db file, does it mean it is same as removing app and reinstalling an app ? thereby all configuration settings or any cached data of previous version is lost when there is an update ? and there is no way for updated version to find any data from previous version ?

Comment: Data stored in the sandbox is kept in place when your application is updated.

Comment: Thanks, so essentially I can copy my db file in the sandbox folder to let the new version access it. true right ?

Comment: Correct. You'll just need some help from the user to do that, as the sandboxed application can't reach outside of its sandbox to get the old database file itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanism to migrate the data of an existing App into the sandbox: [Migrating an App to a Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/MigratingALegacyApp/MigratingAnAppToASandbox.html) on developer.apple.com

This is done once the newly sandboxed app is launched the first time. If you can determine  where the database was stored, you can migrate it into the sandbox.